# Ubuntu 17.10 Mini iso - Gnome Vanilla doesn't show up after installation

Tags: gnome, system-installation, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu with the mini iso, where you can choose the packages to install. I only chose "Gnome 3 vanilla", but when it boots up, I don't get a GUI. Do I need to manually activate it? It asks me to login by username and password, but I never get redirected to a gui, I only see the console.

[image]

Comment: Was this an upgrade to an older installation, or a new installation?  Did you select to encrypt your user directory, or the entire disk?

Comment: @Charles New install. I encrypted home AND the entire disk (was asked for home first). :)

Comment: I need a few minutes - I've tested what you did (minus the encryption) and ran into the same problem, and I'm testing a way out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the following:
I installed it with no packages, then I logged in and ran `sudo apt install gnome-core`. After a reboot, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that using the selection of "Vanilla gnome desktop" in a mini.iso install installs **only** those files that are required to run a vanilla gnome desktop on a running Ubuntu system - many files are not installed, including the display manager (gdm) and the passkey subsystems, used for disk decryption.

---

What you can try (this may not work)

At the login that you have shown above, enter the command `sudo tasksel` and scroll down to "Ubuntu Desktop".  Select "Ubuntu Desktop", press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform the installation.  This will download and install approximately 1100 files, including all of the normally found programs ad utilities found in a full installation .iso.  `tasksel` did throw an error when it had finished, but a system reboot brought up a full working Ubuntu desktop.

Following this (if it works) you can `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop` to get the regular gnome desktop.

---

Why this *may not work* in your case:  You have an encrypted disk, and I believe that the required libraries to unlock the keyring have not been loaded.  This would mean that Ubuntu is unable to access your hard disk and installation of anything would not be possible.

There may be a way around this, but I suspect that it will be easier to start over (selecting "Ubuntu Desktop") given that this is a new installation.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I already found a workaround: Just install it with no packages, then login. Install `gnome-core` and reboot. This works with encryption and everything. :)

Comment: You should consider adding that as an answer

Comment: Will do! [10chars]